# Refreshing a DBML diagram?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql

Really stupid question, sorry, but I can't find it on google (I'm sure it's in a screencast or something somewhere). I have a DBML (linq2sql classes) diagram and I've changed the underlying database. In VS2008, how do I "refresh" the diagram? There's no View-->Refresh or RightClick->Refresh or Update option.

As it stands now, I have to recreate the entire linq2sql classes every time I update the underlying db.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

right click and select "run custom tool" (in solution explorer on dbml file)

Comment: Well that's a bit non-intuitive. Thanks!

Comment: hell yeah, it took me some time to discover "custom tool" is actually the thing that generates the calsses :)

Comment: That doesn't update the DBML file with database changes. It triggers the code generator that generates C# or VB code from the DBML file. DB changes still need to be propagated to the DBML file one way or another - see my answer.

Comment: Brilliant. It worked perfectly for the layout; putting al unadded tables in the topleft of the diagram. Saved me a lot of work.

Comment: @YanSklyarenko, The same goes for me, nothing is happening.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to bring database changes into your DBML diagram then you can:

a) remove the changed entities from the designer diagram and re-drag them. You will lose any customizations (e.g. class and property name changes etc).

b) manually update the diagram, adding/removing classes, member properties, etc.

c) Use a third party tool capable of comparing and updating the DBML file with the underlying database. One such tool is my add-in, [Huagati DBML/EDMX Tools](http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/). It adds a bunch of features to the L2S designer in VS2008 and VS2010, including update/sync, comparison, mass-renaming, name rule enforcement, documentation from extended properties/indexes/etc, multiple 'views' per dbml diagram etc.

Comment: If/when you manually update the diagram by adding it in the view (one could also edit the .xml in some text-editor), be sure to not only set the `name`, but also set the `source` (to the appropriate column). 
That will prevent this error-message: `An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name.`

Answer (score 1):

First you must update the .sdf file to the .dbml file. I did it by opening the cmd prompt, and  directing the path equal to the SqlMetal.exe path. after that change the directory to where the .sdf database is, then typing in "SqlMetal.exe (nameofdatabase).sdf /dbml:(nameofdatabase).dbml". After this right click and select "run custom tool" (in solution explorer on dbml file). That should do it (at least for me it did).